# Scope issue with a sequence of fadeIn's

Tags: javascript, animation, scope, setinterval

I the following code I have a UL with x3 LI's.  I want the LI's to fadeIn in a sequence but am loosing scope somewhere I think.  The problem is that only the last item in the sequence is run.  I initially thought this was to do with a loop, so I removed all of them.  Any help would be great.

Thanks is Advance.

```
function Sequence() {
    var sequence = [];
    var pos = 0;

    Sequence.prototype.add = function(obj) {
        sequence.push(obj);
    };

    Sequence.prototype.start = function() {
        sequence[pos].run();
    };

    Sequence.prototype.next = function() {
        pos++;
        sequence[pos].run();
    }; 
};

function fadeIn(params) {
    this.id = params.id;
    this.onComplete = params.onComplete;

    var self = this;
    var timer;
    var i = params.opacity;

    fadeIn.prototype.run = function(){
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            params.element.style.opacity = i / 10;
            i++;

            if (i / 10 == 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                self.onComplete();
            }
        }, params.fps);
    }
};

var sequence = new Sequence();
var fader = document.getElementById('fader1');
var items = fader.getElementsByTagName("li");

sequence.add(new fadeIn({
    "id": "instance_0",
    "element": items[0],
    "opacity": 0,
    "fps": 80,
    "onComplete": function() {
        sequence.next();
    }
}));

sequence.add(new fadeIn({
    "id": "instance_1",
    "element": items[1],
    "opacity": 0,
    "fps": 80,
    "onComplete": function() {
        sequence.next();
    }
}));

sequence.start();
```

Comment: If you add four spaces to the front of every single line of code, it should format it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a scope issue. The problem is in the line:

```
fadeIn.prototype.run = function(){
```

When you define a method on the `prototype`, you're defining the method on *all* instances of the `fadeIn` class. So each time you call the constructor, you're redefining the method with the new `params` in the closure.

The solution is to define the method on `this` (or, as you've renamed it, `self`), which is the new instance, rather than the class:

```
self.run = function(){
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/wrQMa/3/

Comment: Hi Nick, Outstanding response.  Not only have I been enlightened by your explanation, I have a jsFiddle to see it in action.  Thanks you very much for taking the time.